# EV charger individual cable insulation

Tags: cables, wire, insulation, electric-vehicle, insulation-voltage

Are the internal conductor strands inside the Level 1, level 2, level 3 EV chargers bare or do they have a coat of insulation? I know the conductor strands combined as a wire have a sheath of rubber or some insulation. But do the individual strands have a layer of coating of some sort like enamel/ varnish or not?
Also, Do EV charger cables have Litz wire?

Comment: Why would you insulate the individual stands before twisting them together into one wire?

Comment: To reduce the skin effect in AC cables especially at high frequency. There is a special wire called Litz wire that is used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire I was wondering if EV cable chargers use it.

Comment: OK, and what frequency do you think EV chargers run at? Would you describe it as "high"?

Answer (score 2):

The individual strands of a stranded conductor are not insulated from each other.  If they were, it would not be possible to make a good connection to all the strands of the conductor.